# AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core 4600+ vs Intel Core2 Duo E8400

Tags: cpu

Which one of these two processors is more powerful?

Comment: Currently, your question is rather vague and subjective. More powerful for doing what? Gaming? Media transcoding? Video editing? Editing your question to contain more details would be useful.

Comment: I meant in general, but I'm gonna just use it for web design and development.

Answer (score 1):

Statistics for you from ~15,000 processor benchmark runs:
[Arithmetic Benchmark](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk/rank2011d/top_device.php?q=c2ffcfe99ba696b0d9e4d3f59da0d2b3ddb6e986f5aacba7cbed95a899bfdabf82b294e7daea&l=en) vs. [MultiMedia Benchmark](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk/rank2011d/top_device.php?q=c2ffcee89aa797b1d8e5d2f49ca1d3b2dcb7e887f4abcaa6caec94a998bedbbe83b395e6dbeb&l=en). Results are real-time.

Or...
[The E8400](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk/rank2011d/show_device.php?q=cca598d1bfcbaec2e2a1cebcd9f9cbebafdab595d0e8dcecdcfa88b585a3caf7c6e088b584a2dae7d6f095f0cdfddba895a497&l=en) vs. [The AMD 6400](http://www.sisoftware.co.uk/rank2011d/show_device.php?q=cca598d994d0f0b1c5adc1aec0e0d6e2c29aa888ccb9d8b494d7b8caaf8fbb8dbd8da680f2cfffd9b08dbc9af2cffed8a09dac8aef8ab787a1d2efdf&l=en)

Answer (score 0):

E8200 will mop the floor with the Athlon. For most tasks, Intel CPUs are superior, AMD having the same architecture since 2003 really drags them down.

AnandTech has [a set of benchmarks](http://www.anandtech.com/bench/Product/35?vs=58) just to show you the massive difference between those two processors.